# Running a Baker from Shadow Tech

Tags: baking

Is it possible to run a baker from [Shadow Tech](https://shadow.tech/usen)?

You can find below customer's allocated configuration:

- 12GB of RAM DDR4 - 2400 MHz
- 256GB Dedicated Storage
- 1 Gb/s Download
- 100 Mb/s upload

Comment: You do not really need a high-performance computer, you only need a high-performance SSD. Currently 8GB of RAM are recommended to run a baker, but usually this is not utilised under normal operation.

Until garbage collection and pruning becomes stable for the node to be used in production, the 256 GB SDD likely does not last very long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have my answer. Shadow Tech doesn't allow you to run a Linux VM.
As soon as I start the Linux VM, it crashes!